# Magento2: How to use different implementations of an interface

Tags: module, magento2.2, di

I am creating supplier imports. In order to do this, I created a base module "ProductImportBase" and two supplier specific modules "ProductImportA" and "ProductImportB". The base module contains stuff like readers for different data (csv, xml etc.) and an import helper. It also defines Api\SupplierSpecificInterface which is implemented in ProductImportA\Helper\ASpecific and ProductImportB\Helper\BSpecific.
The ProductImportBase\Helper\Import looks like a bit like this (simplified):

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Fd\ProductImportBase\Api\SupplierSpecificInterface $supplierSpecific,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->supplierSpecific = $supplierSpecific;
    ...
}

public function processImport()
{
    return $this->supplierSpecific->getProductDataRows();
}
```

I created an abstract controller AbstractImport with Fd\ProductImportBase\Helper\Import being injected in the constructor. Both modules extend this AbstractImport in ProductImportA\Controller\AdminHtml\A\Import and ProductImportB\Controller\AdminHtml\B\Import, respectively.

ProductImportA/etc/di.xml looks like this:

```
<type name="Fd\ProductImportBase\Helper\Import">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supplierSpecific" xsi:type="object">Fd\ProductImportA\Helper\ASpecific</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

ProductImportB/etc/di.xml looks like this:

```
<type name="Fd\ProductImportBase\Helper\Import">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supplierSpecific" xsi:type="object">Fd\ProductImportB\Helper\BSpecific</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Now, I expected that when going to admin/productimport/a/import, ASpecific would be used and when going to admin/productimport/b/import, BSpecific would be used. What actually happens is that in both cases BSpecific is used (ProductImportB comes after ProductImportA in the modules list). Did I misunderstand the di concept? Do I need to approach this differently?
This is on Magento 2.2.4, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a bit of googling, fiddling and some trial and error I found a solution.

I created an interface ProductImportBase\Api\ImportHelperInterface which gets implemented by ProductImportBase\Helper\ImportHelper.

Then I changed ProductImportA\Controller\AdminHtml\A\Import and ProductImportB\Controller\AdminHtml\B\Import to use this interface in their constructors instead of ProductImportBase\Helper\Import.

```
class Import extends \Fd\ProductImportBase\Controller\Adminhtml\Import\AbstractImport
{
    public function construct(
        ...
        /* \Fd\ProductImportBase\Helper\Import $importHelper */
        \Fd\ProductImportBase\Api\ImportHelperInterface $importHelper
    ) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In ProductImportA/etc/di.xml I removed the <type name="Fd\ProductImportBase\Helper\Import"> entry, added a virtual type ASpecific and used that virtual type as an argument for ProductImportA\Controller\AdminHtml\A\Import

```
<!--
<type name="Fd\ProductImportBase\Helper\Import">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supplierSpecific" xsi:type="object">Fd\ProductImportA\Helper\ASpecific</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
-->

<virtualType name="AImportHelper" type="Fd\ProductImportBase\Helper\Import">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supplierSpecific" xsi:type="object">Fd\ProductImportA\Helper\ASpecific</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<type name="Fd\ProductImportA\Controller\Adminhtml\A\Import">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="importHelper" xsi:type="object">AImportHelper</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

I did the same thing to ProductImportB/etc/di.xml, respectively.

```
<!--
<type name="Fd\ProductImportBase\Helper\Import">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supplierSpecific" xsi:type="object">Fd\ProductImportB\Helper\BSpecific</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
-->

<virtualType name="BImportHelper" type="Fd\ProductImportBase\Helper\Import">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="supplierSpecific" xsi:type="object">Fd\ProductImportB\Helper\BSpecific</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<type name="Fd\ProductImportB\Controller\Adminhtml\B\Import">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="importHelper" xsi:type="object">AImportHelper</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Now everything works as intended.